# Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Here is my issue:
I'm trying to make a web api in asp.net using an SDK designed in .net framework. The DLLs have some references to some libraries not available in asp.net. The dlls are read only so changing the dependencies to the asp.net equivalent is kinda out of question. Currently I'm stuck on this system.web error and I cannot reference it in the project.

Is there any way to salvage this or should I make a a windows service as well and then make a connection between that and the web API somehow?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.